# fatal error No such file or directory compilationin

Tags: ros, build, include

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I use groovy/ROS with catkin and Eclipse IDE.
I need to use btQuaternion for this reason I do include for this    #include <LinearMath/btQuaternion.h>  in my main program .cpp. Of course  LinearMath exist in  tf2 package. I add in package.xml the following :     <build_depend>tf2</build_depend>  <run_depend>tf2</run_depend> . Additinaly I go to propertise->C/C++Include Paths and symbols -> Add External Include Path -> /opt/ros/groovy/stacks/geometry_experimental/tf2/include. However the results were not satisfactory and after build project I get following error:

fatal error: LinearMath/btQuaternion.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated. make[2]: *

or all result of built of project are:

10:27:24 **** Build of project move_monsun@move_monsun ****
/usr/bin/make -j8 all
/usr/bin/cmake -H/home/amory/catkin_ws/src/move_monsun -B/home/amory/catkin_ws/src/move_monsun --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/amory/catkin_ws/src/move_monsun/CMakeFiles /home/amory/catkin_ws/src/move_monsun/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/amory/catkin_ws/src/move_monsun' /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/move_monsun.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/move_monsun.dir/depend make[2]: Entering directory` /home/amory/catkin_ws/src/move_monsun'
cd /home/amory/catkin_ws/src/move_monsun && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/amory/catkin_ws/src/move_monsun /home/amory/catkin_ws/src/move_monsun /home/amory/catkin_ws/src/move_monsun /home/amory/catkin_ws/src/move_monsun /home/amory/catkin_ws/src/move_monsun/CMakeFiles/move_monsun.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/amory/catkin_ws/src/move_monsun' /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/move_monsun.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/move_monsun.dir/build make[2]: Entering directory` /home/amory/catkin_ws/src/move_monsun'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/amory/catkin_ws/src/move_monsun/CMakeFiles 4
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/move_monsun.dir/src/move_monsun.cpp.o
/usr/bin/c++   -Dmove_monsun_EXPORTS -DROS_PACKAGE_NAME="move_monsun" -fPIC -I/home/amory/catkin_ws/src/move_monsun/include -I/opt/ros/groovy/include    -o CMakeFiles/move_monsun.dir/src/move_monsun.cpp.o -c /home/amory/catkin_ws/src/move_monsun/src/move_monsun.cpp
/home/amory/catkin_ws/src/move_monsun/src/move_monsun.cpp:2:37: **fatal error: LinearMath/btQuaternion.h: No such file or directory**
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/move_monsun.dir/src/move_monsun.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/amory/catkin_ws/src/move_monsun' make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/move_monsun.dir/all] Error 2 make[1]: Leaving directory` /home/amory/catkin_ws/src/move_monsun'
make: *** [all] Error 2

10:27:27 Build Finished (took 2s.764ms)

Have any one Idee or solution?

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53780/fatal-error-no-such-file-or-directory-compilationin/) by [underwater](https://answers.ros.org/users/1303/underwater/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-01-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not super familiar with building in eclipse, but you may be missing a part of your include path.  The full path to btQuaternion.h is:

```
/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/geometry_experimental/tf2/include/tf2/LinearMath/btQuaternion.h
```

Your eclipse-property setting only goes up to: `.../geometry_experimental/tf2/include`, but I think it should also include an additional `tf2` directory.

You could also try to compile the package directly from the command line with rosbuild to see if that works.  If so, then maybe you just need to re-run `make eclipse-project` and see if that fixes things.

---

Originally posted by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) with karma: 4976 on 2013-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0